# Twitter: Number of tweets OR get more tweets

Tags: twitter, get, titanium, tweets

I would like to know how can I get all tweets from a certain hash tag?
I am currently using the following code:

> xhr.open("GET","http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23PrayForJapan");

This only returns me 15 tweets. Does anyone know how to make it return more?

Also, I have got a code to get me the tweets of a certain screen name, this only returns 20 tweets, how can i ask the following 20 tweets?

The code i used for that is:

> xhr.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Eminem");

I'm using titanium to create this, but I don't think that is an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually add `count=x` as parameter to the query string to get up to x tweets (for the search api it seems to be `rpp`). Query string parameters are added to the base url via `?` and each individual parameter is then separated by `&` as in `http://api?user=1&count=4`

Most of the time, it is better though to remember the last tweets and then add `?since_id=x` as this way you only get tweets you did not see before.

Have a look at the [api documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc).

Comment: When I try the count or rpp method it says it needs authentication. I guess this isn't normal? I tried this link: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5?screen_name=Eminem  Am I doing something wrong with that?

Comment: You need t have a look at the individual fetch method of the docs page to see if the method needs authentication or not.

Comment: Well, when I don't use the count or rpp tag, it doesn't require authentication, otherwise it does. And on the doc it says the authentication is false (unless it's protected by user)

Comment: the link i used to see the parameters is this: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Sorry - dunno. User timelines may require authentication, as the first paragraph says.

Comment: You have to separate parameters with a `&` not a `?`. https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5&screen_name=Eminem

Comment: @abraham of course - the ? is the separator after the base url - I will edit my answer